# Minecraft keeps crashing and restarting launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I click Play on the launcher, it attempts to download some part of Minecraft, crashes, opens again, and then will continue to repeat except that it attempts to download a different piece each time.

I have no mods installed, I have the latest Java, and I erased everything and redownloaded Minecraft, but still have the same issue. Here is what the Log says:

```
[17:02:05 INFO]: Minecraft Launcher 1.5.3 (through bootstrap 5) started on windows...
[17:02:05 INFO]: Current time is Nov 6, 2014 5:02:05 PM
[17:02:05 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.name') == 'Windows 7'
[17:02:05 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.version') == '6.1'
[17:02:05 INFO]: System.getProperty('os.arch') == 'x86'
[17:02:05 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.version') == '1.8.0_25'
[17:02:05 INFO]: System.getProperty('java.vendor') == 'Oracle Corporation'
[17:02:05 INFO]: System.getProperty('sun.arch.data.model') == '32'
[17:02:06 INFO]: JFX is already initialized
[17:02:09 INFO]: Refreshing local version list...
[17:02:09 INFO]: Refreshing remote version list...
[17:02:14 INFO]: Refresh complete.
[17:02:15 INFO]: Loaded 1 profile(s); selected 'penguinpellets'
[17:02:15 INFO]: Refreshing auth...
[17:02:15 INFO]: Logging in with access token
[17:03:12 INFO]: Getting syncinfo for selected version
[17:03:12 INFO]: Queueing library & version downloads
[17:03:16 INFO]: Download job 'Version & Libraries' started (16 threads, 33 files)
[17:03:16 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\Users\Todd\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.1\lwjgl-2.9.1.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'... (try 0)
```

***there is a ton more "attempting to download prompts followed by:

```
[18:19:04 INFO]: Attempting to download C:\User
[18:26:39 INFO]: Looking for orphaned versions to clean up...
[18:26:50 INFO]: Looking for old natives & assets to clean up...
[18:27:15 ERROR]: Game ended with bad state (exit code -1)
[18:27:15 INFO]: Ignoring visibility rule and showing launcher due to a game crash
[18:27:15 INFO]: Deleting C:\Users\Todd\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8\1.8-natives-792446550971815
[18:27:15 WARN]: Couldn't delete C:\Users\Todd\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.8\1.8-natives-792446550971815 - scheduling for deletion upon exit
```

This is a slightly older laptop, but it shouldn't have any issues running minecraft. I'm not much of a computer guy, so I am probably just missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the Game Output also? The "launcher log" isn't as of much of use in this case.

Comment: @PenguinPallets (This may sound like a really stupid question, but depending on what you answer - It'll determine what the problem is.) **What's your internet speed... And are you connected to the internet?**

Comment: Delete .minecraft, download official minecraft, run demo, and run again the launcher you have. It fixed for me. Just let the official download the files.

Comment: As Extreme pointed out above, this is too broad a question to be answered without the Game Output.

Comment: But it seems to be a very specific kind of problem, nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

If your answer to:

> @PenguinPallets (This may sound like a really stupid question, but depending on what you answer - It'll determine what the problem is.) What's your internet speed... And are you connected to the internet? –  aytimothy
> [Minecraft keeps crashing and restarting launcher](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190823/minecraft-keeps-crashing-and-restarting-launcher/190894#comment258688_190823)

contains either one (or more) of these:

- I have an internet speed of <20kB/s (Less than 20 kilobytes per second)
- My internet gets cut from time to time.
- My internet is hogged up by someone else... *(ie. Your bandwidth is 30MB/s. Some family member uses 29.999MB/s while you're left stuck with the remainder "useless" 0.001MB/s)*
- My computer has internet/modem/phone line/whatever connectivity issues.

### Then:

By the looks of it, you may have really slow internet... And the launcher did not download the Minecraft files properly even though the launcher thinks it has downloaded the whole package correctly.
From there, your launcher starts the half-downloaded game.. Which then crashes.

The only way to fix this is to do the following:

1. (If you want) - Delete your whole `.minecraft` folder and restart the installation from scratch.
2. Trigger a "Forced Update", and let it update, or: Re-install/download with an uninterrupted internet connection.

The only reason that you would have tonnes of retries to download a file is slow or constantly interrupted internet connections.